# Linux Mint will not boot up on my computer

Tags: boot, drivers, linux-mint, rufus

I have a Razer Blade 2016 edition computer.  I downloaded a Linux Mint ISO file, and used Rufus to make it a live file system on a USB. I load my computer's boot options by clicking F12 while the computer is loading, and select Linux Mint 64 bit cinnamon.

It then proceeded to load the Linux Mint logo, with the 5 dots activity indicator under it. The indicator shows activity, for a very long time, but it never progresses beyond that.

If I use the same USB on my brother's computer, a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro, it works perfectly and boots in under 30 seconds.

I booted in compatibility mode and got the following screen output:

[image]

It fails to actually start a session in compatibility mode as well.  Does anyone know what may be wrong?

Comment: Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro. I am not sure about the UEFI. I selected MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI. I though this one should work even if I don't have  UEFI.

Comment: It's booting, so that's not the issue.  It might be a driver problem.  It sounds like it's hitting a point where it can't deal with some hardware in your machine.  That's a common issue with Linux and new hardware, it sometimes takes awhile for drivers to catch up.  I'm not sure about Mint, but some distros have a boot option in GRUB, called something like safe mode, that does a more rigorous evaluation of hardware and looks for alternate drivers.

Comment: Is it also called compatibility mode? I tried using compatibility mode and I forgot the error message that I got, but it did not work.

Comment: I believe that's it.  If you got an error message there, that's a good bet as to the problem.  Try it again and write down the message.  That may be the key to the solution.

Comment: Sorry it is a bad picture, I took it with my phone. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EDqkokPA0uyBJhcCxPtKdg1h731I7493fg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are dealing with a hardware incompatibility, stdin error is uncertain though, could be from anything looking for standard input... looking at those new Razor laptops they are really new and cutting edge hardware, I would try a newer distro (Mint is a pretty solid, safe but older distro based on Ubuntu from April), perhaps Ubuntu 16.10, OpenSUSE Leap 42.2, or Fedora 25.

Comment: Tried Ubuntu, doesn't work. Gets stuck at the same place @acejavelin it just again gets stuck on the second dot. Since they are similar systems I assume it's the same process that they are getting stuck on.

Comment: @JeffMorse Consider Fedora 25, I think it is using the 4.8 Kernel, the only distro to do so out of the box thus far, most others use the 4.4 LTS kernel. Otherwise, that error is too generic for me to troubleshoot further

Comment: @JeffMorse, I'm not proficient at reading that console output, but it looks like the Razer's fancy new video may be giving it indigestion.  acejavelin's suggestion of trying a distro with the latest kernel is a good one.  If it is a video driver issue, you could check the NVidia web site to see if they have a Linux driver.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't solve your Mint installation yet, some useful tips to proceed in order:

1- Windows 8.x and 10: how to prepare it for dual boot with Ubuntu or Linux Mint

[How to prepare your PC before Mint installation](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/windows)

2- How to install Linux Mint 18.1 alongside Windows

[Dual boot Windows / Mint](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/mint-install)